# Calculate each letter and the total vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following function that takes input from `txtbox1` and outputs the result in `txtbox2`. The main point is to substitute each letter with a specific numeric value, calculate the value of each word and then display the total of all words. Right now, this function is calculating always to 13. If I type `aaa bbb cc` for example, the result should be. How do I modify the function to do that?

```
aaa = 3
bbb = 15
cc = 14
Total = 32

Private Sub CountLetters(Input As String)

    Dim total As Integer = 0
    Dim dicLetters As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)
    dicLetters.Add("a", 1)
    dicLetters.Add("b", 5)
    dicLetters.Add("c", 7)

    For Each word As String In Input.Split

        Dim wordtotal As Integer = 0
        For Each cc As KeyValuePair(Of Char, Integer) In dicLetters

            wordtotal += cc.Value
        Next

        total += wordtotal

        'Display word totals here

        txtBox2.Text += word.PadRight(12) + "=" + _
                        wordtotal.ToString.PadLeft(5) + vbNewLine
    Next

    'Display total here
    txtBox2.Text += "Total".PadRight(12) + "=" + total.ToString.PadLeft(5)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As logixologist indicated, the issue is your looping through the dictionary and summing up the values of the keys, not the values of the words.

If you have a value for each letter, a Dictionary is a good way to go (if it's only a few letters than a `Select` would be fine as well).

Below is some code that will get the result you're looking for:

```
Dim total As Integer = 0
Dim wordTotal AS Integer
Dim dicLetters As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)
dicLetters.Add("a", 1)
dicLetters.Add("b", 5)
dicLetters.Add("c", 7)

' charValue will be used to hold the result of the TryGetValue below
Dim charValue As Integer

For Each word As String In Input.Split(New Char() { " " })

    wordTotal = 0

    ' Loop through the word
    For Each character As Char in word

        wordTotal += If(dicLetters.TryGetValue(character, charValue) = _
                     True, dicLetters(character), 0)
    Next

    total += wordTotal

    txtBox2.Text += word.PadRight(12) + " = " + _
                    wordTotal.ToString().PadLeft(5) + vbNewLine
Next

txtBox2.Text += "Total:".PadRight(12) + " = " + _
                total.ToString().PadLeft(5)
```

The outer loop is essentially the same - split the input string on " " (space).

Reset the wordTotal counter to 0, and then loop through the current word (using For Each Character to go through the word one character at a time).

The next line uses `TryGetValue` on the dictionary, and if there is a value for the key, it adds the value to `wordTotal`, otherwise it adds 0.

The output will for "aaa bbb cc" will be:

```
aaa          =     3
bbb          =    15
cc           =    14
Total:       =    32
```

Comment: I like your solution better anyways:).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: What you are doing in this statement:

```
For Each cc As KeyValuePair(Of Char, Integer) In dicLetters
wordtotal += cc.Value
Next
```

For every key value pair in the dictionary add them up... so it adds up 1, 5 and 7 to give you 13.

Why not put a SELECT/CASE Statement checking the value of each letter against the dictionary and adding that to `wordtotal`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I am still unable to get the desired outcome.

Comment: How do I implement the select/case statement?

Comment: The easier way to do this is not using a dictionary with key value pairs unless you have a lot of key/value pairs.  I dont have vb.net open right now but I'll look at when I can.

Comment: I have a value for each letter.